# Pre-render linear gradients collapsible elements in react-native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, linear-gradients

is it possible to pre-render linear gradients (expo-linear-gradient). I am rendering about 350 gradients, most of which have 2/3 colours, in a collapsible (react-native-collapsible) element. It freezes for around 5 seconds when expanding/shrinking the collapsible or pressing on a gradient. Here is the element I am rendering multiple times:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.changeColour(props.colours)}>
  <LinearGradient
    style={styles.container}
    colors={props.colours}
    start={[0, 1]}
    end={[1, 0]}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

All changeColor does is set another’s linear gradient colours to the one tapped.

I store these elements in a simple array, where I loop through the colours from a json file and push them to the mentioned array. I render these elements directly (ie. return({arrayWithComponents}) ). I only notice this poor performance when I render these elements.

I tried setting each linear gradient a unique key, as a warning appeared, but performance tanked even more - it even froze the app a bit when opening it. I also tried using a FlatList but performance degraded even more.

[Gradients I am using, although I removed the gradients with more than 4 colours](https://github.com/ghosh/uiGradients/blob/master/gradients.json)